# Serialize Object to XML in with specific format

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Im trying to Serialize an object( a class in this case) with an specific fomat.
I got something like this:

```
<ns:pay xmlns:ns="http://example.uri.here">
<ns:Payment>
    <ns:customerKeyValue>5555</ns:customerKeyValue>
    <ns:bankCode>BBBB</ns:bankCode>
    <ns:paymentAmount>456</ns:paymentAmount>
    <ns:paymentCategory>KD</ns:paymentCategory>
    <ns:paymentMode>AC</ns:paymentMode>
    <ns:referenceNumber>123A</ns:referenceNumber>
    <ns:userID>Test2</ns:userID>
    <ns:invoiceNumber>61</ns:invoiceNumber>
</ns:Payment>
</ns:pay>
```

I have the class that have each element but when i serialize it it convert its to this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns_x003A_pay xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://example.uri.here">
  <CustomerKeyValue>5555</CustomerKeyValue>
  <BankCode>BBBB</BankCode>
  <PaymentAmount>456</PaymentAmount>
  <PaymentCategory>KD</PaymentCategory>
  <PaymentMode>AC</PaymentMode>
  <ReferenceNumber>123A</ReferenceNumber>
  <UserID>Test2</UserID>
  <InvoiceNumber>61</InvoiceNumber>
</ns_x003A_pay>
```

So anyone can help me with that?
The method that im using to convert to xml is this:

```
public static string SerializeToXMLString(object ObjectToSerialize)
    {
        MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(ObjectToSerialize.GetType());
        ser.Serialize(mem, ObjectToSerialize);
        ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
        return ascii.GetString(mem.ToArray());
    }
```

note:
to specify the namespace and class name i'm using this:
[XmlRootAttribute( "ns:pay", Namespace = "http://example.uri.here")]
in the class

If you haven't noted every XML element start with

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Your target XML is invalid as it contains multiple root nodes, so the only way to get invalid XML is by hard-coding strings, no way with a decent XML serializer/parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok guys I just found the answer here to my questions and i'm writing here to help people with this problem:

```
    public static string SerializeToXMLString(object ObjectToSerialize)
        {
            //
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("ns", "http://example.uri.here");
            //
            //
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(ObjectToSerialize.GetType());
            XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            writerSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, writerSettings))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, ObjectToSerialize,ns);
            }
            return  stringWriter.ToString();
}
```

---

To solve the prefix :
I created a XmlSerializerNamespaces object and added the prefix that I wanted and the namespace.

To solve the ns:pay ns:payment
I created two classes: Payment and Pay.

In the pay class i added this:
[XmlRoot("pay", Namespace = "http://example.uri.here")]

In the Payment Class i added this:
[XmlRoot("pay")]

Pay Class has a property of type payment. That create the xml in this style:

```
<ns:pay>
<ns:payment
element here
</ns:payemnt>
</ns:pay>
```

---

Thank you guys. Sorry that I ask and found the question almost 30 minutes after asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [LINQtoXSD](http://linqtoxsd.codeplex.com/) (not XmlSerializer, sure :-)